# Python 3 type hints in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-typing

I have python `def` definition which seems working for python3:

```
def get_default_device(use_gpu: bool = True) -> cl.Device:
```

Under python2 I get the following syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map_copy.py", line 9, in <module>
    import utility
  File "/home/root/pyopencla/ch3/utility.py", line 6
    def get_default_device(use_gpu: bool = True) -> cl.Device:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to make type hints compatible with python2?

Comment: By removing the type hints

Comment: maybe https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html#type-checking-python-2-code

Answer (score 1):

Function annotations were introduced in [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) for Python 3.0. The usage of annotations as type hints was formalized in in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for Python 3.5+.

Any version before 3.0 then will not support the syntax you are using for type hints at all. However, PEP 484 [offers a workaround](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code), which some editors may choose to honor. In your case, the hints would look like this:

```
def get_default_device(use_gpu=True):
    # type: (bool) -> cl.Device
    ...
```

or more verbosely,

```
def get_default_device(use_gpu=True  # type: bool
                      ):
    # type: (...) -> cl.Device
    ...
```

The PEP explicitly states that this form of type hinting should work for *any* version of Python, if it is supported at all.

Comment: PEP484 isn't the relevant source in this case. Type hints are just an application of function annotations, which where introduced by [PEP3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) for Python 3.0.

Comment: @chepner. I've updated. While I agree that annotations were valid since Py 3.0, the relevant PEP is still 484 (which references 3107).

Comment: But why didn't they just allow and ignore the syntax in py2 so you could use the same source code at least?

Comment: @Trass3r. I don't think there was a `from __future__ import ...` option for this because it would have involved making too many changes to the interpreter.