# python setup.py egg_info failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pycharm, type-hinting

I just downloaded Pycharm community 2023.2, also using python 2.7 interpreter
I'm trying to run the following:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/19/e63fb4e0d20e48bd2167bb7e857abc0e21679e24805ba921a224df8977c0/pip-23.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "local\temp\pip-build-fagwaz\pip\setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in local\temp\pip-build-fagwaz\pip\
You are using pip version 20.3.4, however version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

And also whenever I run the code, I get the following issue:

Info on the packages I need to import (but when i download them it doesn't help).

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Each time I try something it either doesn't compile or doesn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 type hints in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306458/python-3-type-hints-in-python-2)

Comment: It actually does. You're using Python 2.7 which does not support the type hinting syntax where the error is shown: `rel_path: str`.

Answer (score 2):

pip versions >20.x removed Python 2 support. You are using the latest possible version which is compatible with Python 2.

The error you are getting is due to new syntax, called *type-hints*, that is only compatible with versions of Python 3.

Comment: What do u just me to change? I have to use python 2.7 that's for sure.

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to ask for. You cannot further upgrade pip under Python 2.7 to a higher version.